# Не работает код, проверяющий значения списка из датафрейма и выполняющий по нему действия

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Беру датафрейм и делаю из него список, прохожусь по каждой строке чтобы скачать данные с yahoo finance. Затем проверяю условия скаченного - data на соответвие в нем столбце Vol определенным параметрам и хочу записать затем данные в столбец датафрейма - удовлетворили условию или нет.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('111.csv')
```

Вот код - если в него поставить как здесь date_start_l[i] / date_end_l[i], то работать он не будет полностью. Хотя мы просто берем значения даты когда хотим скачать данные с яху. `time.sleep(5)` нужен только для того чтобы не заблочили IP если много качать.

```
symbol_l = list(df.symbol.values)
date_start_l = list(df.date_start.values)
date_end_l = list(df.date_end.values)
state_l = list(df.state.values)
total_l = list(df.total.values)

for i in range(len(df)):

    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol_l[i], start=datetime.datetime(date_start_l[i]), end=datetime.datetime(date_end_l[i]))
    total = data['Volume'].sum()/30
    
    if total >= 1000000:
        total_l[i] = total
        state_l[i] = 1
        
    print(symbol_l[i],total_l[i],state_l[i])
    time.sleep(5)

pass
```

Сам код с yahoo finance работает без проблем:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime 
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', 
                          start=datetime.datetime(2006, 10, 1), 
                          end=datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1))
df
```

Но даже, если не изменять значения start-end datetime.datetime 2006, 10, 1/2012, 1, 1 - все равно после скачивания в `for i in range(len(df)):` будет ошибка `KeyError: 'Date'`, хотя все скачается и даже посчитается total! Но не перейдет на другую строку и не запишется в датафрейм.

То есть, по факту не работает адекватно замена start-end datetime.datetime, затем ошибка яху и в конце не записывается значение в датафрейм.

Comment: а мне кажется, или у вас в файле data_start и data_end, а в коде date_start и date_end ?

Comment: Зачем вы всё в `list` превращаете? На правильность это не влияет, но это лишнее преобразование, исходные `numpy.array`, которые лежат в `values` работают быстрее, чем питоновский `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `import datetime` на `from datetime import datetime` для простоты дальнейшего кода, а затем приведите даты к нужному формату правильно:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol_l[i], start=datetime.strptime(date_start_l[i], '%Y,%m,%d'),
                              end=datetime.strptime(date_end_l[i], '%Y,%m,%d'))
    total = data['Volume'].sum()/30
    
    if total >= 1000000:
        total_l[i] = total
        state_l[i] = 1
        
    print(symbol_l[i],total_l[i],state_l[i])
    time.sleep(5)
```